# How to know the number difference between 2 tables in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I really need to know the query to display another field which is I want to name it as "number_difference" between 2 tables that required a numeric (in this case as a quantity).
I have 2 tables that totally same, let say, I modify the value from table A so some value in table A different with table B. And I want to join it into 1 table that display rows that some values were modified. I already get the result by this query :

**

> select a.T1, a.T2 a.T3 ... from A where not exists (select * from B
>   where a.T1=b.T1 and a.T2=b.T2 and a.T3=b.T3)

**

This query works well. But, I want to add more field, the difference number between this 2 field (quantity) in 2 different tables. So let say, a.T3 and b.T3 are quantities. And want to display it as "number_difference" next to field (T2) which I display. Sorry I can't post images, they say I need at least 10 reputation to post. Please help me master, how can I make it everytime I use join/inner join it always display soo many rows that I only need the rows which a value from 1 table I have modified.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How can you take difference of two values, if the matching row doesn't exist in `B`?  Edit your question and add sample data and desired results.

Comment: Yeah this question is very vague and we need more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can get something like this

```
Select * From A Where A.id  not in( Select Id from B)
```

or

```
Select A.* From A left join B on A.id = B.id Where A.id <> B.id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are specifically targeting a situation with two identical tables,  where one underwent UPDATE operations only (no INSERT), and you want to identify those records which were modified, then:

```
select a.* from a, b where a.id=b.id and ( a.c1!=b.c1 or a.c2!=b.c2)
```